# The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "swatch_image" component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, production-mode

I get a report error when I try to edit my theme configuration in "Content -> Design -> Configuration

When I click on Edit over my Theme I See a error sended to Report, and in teh report the follow error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:87:"The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "swatch_image" component.";i:1;s:7760:"#0 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(360): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
    #1 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(360): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
    #2 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(360): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
    #3 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(272): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
    #4 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('design_config_f...', Array, false)
    #5 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('design_config_f...', NULL, Array)
    #6 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'design_config_f...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
    #7 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
    #8 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
    #9 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
    #10 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #11 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #12 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
    #13 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
    #14 /var/www/html/www.solopide.me/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
...
```

I'm using Magento 2.1.3 in production Mode.

Any idea about what is the problem?

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by going into the Magento Admin Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced

Then go to Magento_Swatches and marking it as "Enable".

Save Config.

I hope this works for you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

James' answer worked to solve my issue, i would just note that for Magento 2.2 sites, the `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced` section is no longer in the admin. This has been replaced by this system: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html.

But all the more important is for sites that have been migrated to 2.2 that had these modules disabled before the migration. For these there is a field in the database in `core_config_data` where these setting persist. This is where these will have to be set to solve this issue.

[image]